# prime division methodology

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

Trying to solve:

Find $a,b,c$ for $31|(5a+7b+11c)$

I found $a=6,b=3,c=1$ as one solution.  Is there a systematic way to find all solutions?

I was thinking take $5a+7b+11c=31n$ and solve by method for Linear Diophantine Equations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarded $\pmod {31},$ the set is a two-parameter set, but the three letters $a,b,c$ can (separately) be altered by any multiples of $31.$

Another way is your $5a+7b+11c-31n = 0,$ which gives what is called an integer lattice, relating to integral quadratic forms. The best known method for finding a reduced, or nearly reduced, basis for a lattice is the LLL algorithm. However, in very small dimension, there are easier ways to work this: all solutions can be parametrized by three integer variables $x,y,z$ as
$$ (a,b,c,n)= (x-y+3z, \; -2x+y+z, \; -2x-3y-2z, \; -x-y)   $$
which comes from the three basis vectors 
$$  ( \; 1, \; -2, \; -2, \; -1 \;),  $$
$$ ( \; -1, \; 1, \; -3, \; -1 \;),  $$
$$ (\; 3, \; 1, \; -2, \;0 \;).  $$

For those who know matrices, we have the matrix
$$ B =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & -2 & -2 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & -3 & -1 \\
3 & 1 & -2 & 0
\end{array}
\right),
$$
we find
$$ B B^T =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
10 & 4 & 5 \\
4 & 12 & 4  \\
5 & 4 & 14 
\end{array}
\right).
$$
This corresponds to an "even" integral lattice, as all entries are integers and all diagonal entries are even. This corresponds to the positive quadratic form
$$ 10 x^2 + 12 y^2 + 14 z^2 + 8 yz + 10 zx + 8 xy,  $$ or
$$ 2 \left( 5x^2 + 6 y^2 + 7 z^2 + 4yz + 5zx +4xy  \right).  $$ 
Note that this is equal to
$$    (x - y + 3  z)^2 + (-2  x + y + z)^2 + (-2  x -3  y - 2  z)^2 + (-x -y)^2 $$
which is the whole point of it.

```
   norm          a    b    c    n
     0           0    0    0    0
    10           1   -2   -2   -1
    12           1   -1    3    1
    14           2    3    0    1
    14           2   -3    1    0
    14           3    1   -2    0
    18           4    0    1    1
    26           1    4   -3    0
    26           3    2    3    2
    30           0    1    5    2
    30           5   -2   -1    0
    34           1    5    2    2
    34           2    2   -5   -1
    34           4   -1   -4   -1
    36           3   -5   -1   -1
    38           0    6   -1    1
    40           2   -4   -4   -2
    42           3   -4    4    1
    46           5   -1    4    2
    46           5    4   -2    1
    48           2   -2    6    2
    50           6    3    1    2
    50           6   -3    2    1
    52           7    1   -1    1
    54           2    4    5    3
    56           4    6    0    2
    56           4   -6    2    0
    56           6    2   -4    0
    62           0    5   -6   -1
    62           3    0   -7   -2
    62           4    1    6    3
    62           6   -4   -3   -1
    66           1   -7    4    0
    66           4    5   -5    0
    68           1   -3   -7   -3
    68           3    7   -3    1
    68           5    5    3    3
    70           1   -8   -1   -2
    72           8    0    2    2
    74           0    7    4    3
    74           1    0    8    3
    74           5   -3   -6   -2
    74           7   -5    0    0
    74           8   -1   -3    0
    78           1    3   -8   -2
    78           4   -7   -3   -2
    78           7    2    4    3
   norm          a    b    c    n
```

Well, this was interesting. I decided to figure out how to prove that my set of three vectors really was an integral basis for the lattice, not just over the rationals. Easier than I expected, and cute. I just did ordinary Gaussian elimination, but without dividing by any integers, only multiplying by integers, and I (easily, by hand) took the rectangular matrix i called $B$ to
$$ W =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 8 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 5 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 31 & 11
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Given any solution quadruple of integers $(a,b,c,n),$ we simply take $a$ times the first row plus $b$ times the second row. Now, any two pairs $(c_1, n_1)$ and $(c_2, n_2)$ of integers such that
$$ 11 c_1 - 31 n_1 =  11 c_2 - 31 n_2  $$
relate in a predictable way, we must have
$$ (c_1 - c_2, n_1 - n_2) = t \cdot (31,11)  $$ for integer $t,$ because
$$ 11 (c_1 - c_2) - 31 (n_1 - n_2) = 0.  $$ That is one of those number theory things (i.e, $c_1-c_2$ must be divisible by $31$ and $n_1-n_2$ must be divisible by $11$ and so forth). As a result, we can find the full quadruple $(a,b,c,n)$ by adding an integer multiple of the third row $(0,0,31,11).$ Very nice the way it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ {\rm mod}\ 31\!:\,\ 5a+7b+11c\equiv 0\overset{\large\times\, 6}\iff -a + 11b+4c\equiv 0\iff a\equiv 11b+4c$